# Automation error using Selenium.EdgeDriver

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

while running the below code.

```
Dim edge As New Selenium.EdgeDriver
Dim By As New By
Dim smartbuyURL As String
smartbuyURL = "http://bayer-t.procurement-eu.ariba.com" 'PROD: http://bayer.procurement-eu.ariba.com

With edge
    .Get smartbuyURL
    End With
```

here i have done all the installation as per the latest versions and while running the "edgedrvier.exe" its

saying that "Edge WebDriver has been successfully started on"  While running a code edge or chrome.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is ... can you please try to clarify it and, if you are getting an error while the code is running, what is the number and exact text of the error ("successfully started" doesn't sound like an error)?

Comment: The code works for me, it brings up a login screen.

Comment: Welcome Rafiq! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour